Connect jpype to existing JVM
I try to access an API of an java Application from python. The Application is a simulation tool. It has more sophisticated functions but the simplest functions are start, pause and reset the simulation.
I launch the java application like the following:
java -jar lib/simulation.jar

Inside the simulation I have access to two buttons:

start/pause
reset

So far how the GUI of the application looks/works.
So far I understand the JVM is already running at this moment. Now I launch my python script to actually execute the command via API:
import jpype
import jpype.imports
from jpype.types import *

jpype.startJVM(classpath="lib/simulation.jar")

from com.simulation.basic import SimModel

model = SimModel()

model.start()
model.pause()
model.reset()

So the line model.start() throws the first error, that classmethod com.simulation.basic.SimModel.getSimulation() returns null, and so the model is not able to execute method start.
From my perspective it looks like I am able to create successful the APIclass SimModel but it doesn't know about the actual Application, because both instances are spawned in different JVMs.
If my assumption is correct, how could I force the JPype to load the JVM from my already running Application?

Why do you think jpype can connect to an already running JVM? The documentation doesn't mention another method to start it.

I hoped so. Is this one of the big issues of Java? Not being able to access the APIs via different languages? I think jython is not an option since other python dependencies, which are not compatible with jython.

"Not being able to access the APIs via different languages?" Only in the way that you are attempting. After all jpype is working, right? Potentially this could be implemented but maybe it would need more effort.

I am not bound to jpype it was only the first result for running java in python.

I finally understood the issue of the API of the simulation, and jpype actually was the right tool. Sadly it works completely different as I expected in the first place. It launches the simulation but without any GUI implementation.
